# Publishing of Dynamic components

Tags: publishing, 2013-sp1, dynamic-publishing

I have 3 different components(named DC1, DC2, DC3) which are built using 3 different schemas: DS1, DS2, DS3 respectively. The DS3 is used in DS2 and DS2 is used in DS1.

When I publish DC2 using a  dynamic component template, tridion is internally publishing DC1. Is there a way to prevent parent component(DC1) publish when the DC2 gets published?

Comment: Your question quality was not upto the mark and confusing. I have updated it per best of my knowledge; verify if it is correct

Answer (score 2):

As per the SDL Tridion design, this is out of the box behaviour that if you publish a Component using Dynamic Component Templates, the entire chain of linked components will get published; so out-of-box you can not prevent this behaviour. However, Tridion is quite rich in APIs and you can create a custom solution to do so by using any of the following methodology/API (In the order of their recommendation):

- Custom Resolver
- Event System Code

I hope this help.